# Is niqab important so that man don't gaze at woman

Tags: hijab, men-women

If people say that niqab is important so that man do not gaze at woman, then in today's context, there is gay man who also gaze at man, so by this logic, then man should also cover their face because gay man gazing at man is more problematic and fitna in the framework of Islam than man looking at man.

So the question, what is the function of Niqab, is it prevent man from gazing at woman ?

Comment: Niqab is from Arab culture and not Islam.  The function of it will differ between people since Quran and sahih hadith don't define it.

Comment: Firstly, niqab is different than hijab. Hijab is covering the whole body including the face, it is not compulsory; hijab (showing the face only) is sufficient. Secondly, hijab is to protect women from the evil and nasty  lustful men. Lets day a man harasses a woman, what can she do if there is mo mahram??? Women are weak and fragile. While men are strong and can defend themselves against any sexual harassment if it occurs. Plus, being hay is not from the pure nature of humans, but men-women attraction is purely natural.

Answer (score 2):

Hijab حِجَاب is a partition and not an article of clothing. See 7:46, 17:45, 33:53, 42:51. In Surah An-Nur 24:31, Allah tells women not to display their zinah زِينَة which means beautification or decoration 7:31-32. 28:79, 37:6.

The ayah also tells women to cast their khumur خُمُرِ against their juyub جُيُوبِ which could either mean their cleavage or the opening of their garments 27:12, 28:32. Furthermore Allah orders them to pull their jalabib جَلَابِيبِ over themselves 33:59.

So women were told not to display whatever they use to beautify/decorate themselves with, except that which is apparent of it. This has nothing to do with their natural beauty or husn حُسْنُ such as their face.